# How do you disable modules in bulk via Drush matching a specific pattern?

Tags: 7, drush

Currently I have to disable all of the ubercart modules in bulk, but there are too many of them to do it one at a time via the modules page. And doing it via drush doesn't disable every module related to ubercart sometimes. Is there a quick way to disable these modules via Drush in bulk matching a specific pattern?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the drush recipe combined with a few other commands to disable modules in bulk:

```
drush pm-list | ack uc_ | ack Enabled | grep "\((.*)\)" | awk -F'(' '{print $2}' | awk -F')' '{print $1}' | xargs -i drush dis '{}' -y
```

**Broken down:**

1. `drush pm-list` lists out all of your modules
2. `ack uc_` returns only the lines matching "uc_"
3. `ack Enabled` returns only the enabled modules
4. `grep "\((.*)\)"` matches the words in parentheses
5. `awk -F'(' '{print $2}'` breaks up the line starting with the `(` character
6. `awk -F')' '{print $1}'` breaks up the line starting with the `)` character
7. `xargs -i drush dis '{}' -y` runs the returned result into drush disable command with the `-y` parameter for yes to all.

---

[Thanks to greg_1_anderson](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/74840/how-do-you-disable-modules-in-bulk-via-drush-matching-a-specific-pattern?newsletter=1&nlcode=19002%7Ce24e#comment82716_74841), I updated it to be a bit shorter.

```
drush pm-list --status=enabled --pipe | grep 'uc_' | xargs -i drush pm-disable '{}' -y
```

Comment: This is cool, but could probably be simplified somewhat using `drush pm-list --pipe | grep uc_`.

Comment: im sure it can be simplified, its just that im using what i know so far.. kinda long and barbaric i must say.

Comment: `drush pm-list --status=enabled --pipe` will return only the enabled modules. Sorry, didn't notice you were awk'ing out the disabled modules. Also, you can drop the awk, since pm-list is outputting one module name per line and nothing more.

Comment: For clarity/readability and making it easier to replace the pattern for non shell experts, perhaps doing it like `PATTERN='uc_'; drush pm-list --status=enabled --pipe | grep ${PATTERN} | xargs -i drush pm-disable '{}' -y` would be even better, if a bit more verbose.

Comment: I found I had to remove the xargs -i argument. I think it maybe should be -I (capitalised), but also --pipe returns string rather than separate lines, so that can happily be fed straight into drush pm-*